# Experimenting with xmls for android UI. Would like to know if there's a better way to accomplish my task

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's the current *main screen* for a toy project that I'm working on (.xml follows):

[image: main_screen]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2" > 

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/resume_button"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/resume" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/newgame_button"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/new_game" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/quit_button"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/quit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I got the layout that I wanted, but did I go about it in a good way?  Is there a better way to get this result?

Secondly, say I wanted to transform my original screen to this: 
[image: main_transformed_1]

Is a good way to do this with a combination of alignment via gravity (`LEFT`) and padding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first part of my question, part of what I'm wondering is: Is using weights with linear layouts/gravity options a good way to get this layout.  Would some other model be better?

Comment: I think ,you have answered the question yourself,didn't it worked;

Comment: Havent you divided the views by weights,by using just one LL for (a)
and use the LEFT alignment to buttons

Comment: @FAST, just because it worked, doesn't mean in it's a good way to do it.

Comment: using LL twice cant be the good solution ,because it can be easily archived by single LL ,

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the redundant `LinearLayout` that encloses those buttons

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2" > 

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/resume_button"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/resume" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/newgame_button"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/new_game" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/quit_button"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/quit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and set each button with `android:layout_weight="1"`. You can also set parent linearlayout to `android:layout_weight="4"` to get back the about the same weight.

Comment: Yeah, removing the *redundant* layout is a good idea, but it actually adds a decent amount of code to get the positioning correct (and there's an issue that I don't know how to resolve, see last sentence). Remember, I want a 3:2 ratio of the Text View to the total area of the buttons and want things to be centered. I also wanted the buttons to each be the same size; how can I do that without grouping them together?

Comment: Come to think about it, if you want those buttons to be exactly same size then the enclosed linearlayout is not that redundant, as it wraps the width around the largest button and all its child buttons will follow. I think there wouldn't be any other better way to do that.

Comment: using another Layout is a better idea if there is a large number of views of same kind ,well here in this case they are three buttons ,you may like to set the attributes of each button differently and deal with them differently in the code .